# Stacked chart type throwing error

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I am using stacked chart type in my ASP.NET page.
While I was running the page, it shows the error:

> server error-in Application Chart Area Axes Object - Stacked chart
>   types must have the same number of data points for all series.

How to fix this? Can any one help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well do you have all datapoints ? As it says seems you are missing some .Like say if you have two X1 and X2 then all source would need those points

Comment: chrtsc.Series[0].XValueMember = Convert.ToString(lstDataSender[0].ReturnDataset.Tables[0].Columns[6]);
                        chrtsc.Series[0].YValueMembers = Convert.ToString(lstDataSender[0].ReturnDataset.Tables[0].Columns[5]);

Comment: i have given like this,can u correct me if there s a mistake..

Comment: I think you should assign the `ColumnName` and not the column itself as the datamember `...Columns[6].ColumnName)`

Comment: even if i add with columns[6].columnname also the same error comes.

Comment: What abt the other series, you would need multiple series for a stacked chart and also are you assigning the DataSource too ?

Comment: ya am using multiple series and assigned the data source.

Comment: Can you edit the post with your code and if possible a data sample as what you are binding, columns and rows

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the following method on your chart after databinding:

```
Chart1.AlignDataPointsByAxisLabel();
```

This ensures all data series have the same number of data points by filling in any empty spaces with 'fake' points.